# Semicolon in "These reasons show why England even went to America in the first place [?] god, gold, and glory"

Tags: grammar, punctuation, semicolons

Should there be a semicolon between *place* and *god* in this sentence, in place of the [?]?

> These reasons show why England even went to America in the first place **[?]** god, gold, and glory.

Comment: The sentence ends with a list; replace the question mark with a colon rather than a semicolon.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited to [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

The sentence ends with a list; replace the question mark with a colon rather than a semicolon.